# cannot execute sh script with golang - permission denied

Tags: linux, go, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to make my go program to execute a script file (.sh) that in my Linux (ubuntu) system and every time I'm getting the following error:

> Got command status: fork/exec /home/myname/Code/MyProj/Server/src/: permission denied

the script that I'm trying to run is pretty simple:

**temp.sh:**

> echo tempscript:$1

**temp.sh permissions:**

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 myname myname 19 oct 13 13:33 temp.sh

the golang code I'm using to run the script :

```
output, err := exec.Command("/home/myname/MyProj/Server/src/", "temp.sh").CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error when running command.  Output:")
    fmt.Println(string(output))
    fmt.Printf("Got command status: %s\n", err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

I have no problem to run this script from the terminal, but when I'm trying to run it from my go problem I'm getting the permission problem, even when I tried to do go build and run my program with sudo permission I'm still getting that error. 
Happy to hear what am I doing wrong and how to solve it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `/home/myname/MyProj/Server/src/` is a directory, you can't execute a directory.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the code like this,

```
output, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "/home/myname/MyProj/Server/src/temp.sh").CombinedOutput()
```

Comment: I have tried this as: exec.Command("/bin/bash", "./mine.sh").CombinedOutput() it fails with:  fork/exec /bin/bash: operation not permitted